# Making a vertical UL slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to create a vertical menu with a fixed height that slides up and down when you press the arrows.

I can't wrap my head around how to work with the offsets to know where to jump to.
Now I take the relative offset from the next li-item and jump to there. But it's doesn't do what it is supposed to do. And also, it's not correct. I think I'd have to know if the bottom of the UL is displayed in the div. If so, the down arrow doesn't have to move anymore. But how can I know?

```
    //get next element
    var offsetNextLi = jQuery($nextElement).position();

    $liScrolledto = $nextElement;

    jQuery("ul#inline_navigation").animate({
        scrollTop: offsetNextLi.top
    }, 500);
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GxL8v/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offset is relative, but your example has a constant li height, so you could use a constant stepping. Or calculate the next invisible outer li element. To do that I worte a little jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/GxL8v/3/

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
     //SLIDE UP
    jQuery("#arrowup").on("click", function () {
        var $ul = $('#inline_navigation');
        var y = $ul.scrollTop();
        var $firstChild = $ul.children().first();
        var step = $firstChild.outerHeight() + parseInt($firstChild.css('marginBottom'),10);

        console.log('before up', y, step);
        if (y >= 0) {
            y -= step;
            console.log('after up', y);

            $ul.stop().animate({
                scrollTop: y
            }, 100);
        }
    });

    //SLIDE DOWN
    $("#arrowdown").on("click", function () {
        var $ul = $('#inline_navigation');
        var y = $ul.scrollTop();
        var h = $ul.height();
        var $firstChild = $ul.children().first();
        var step = $firstChild.outerHeight() + parseInt($firstChild.css('marginBottom'),10);

        console.log('before down', y, step);
        if (h >= y) {
            y += step;
            console.log('after down', y);

            $ul.stop().animate({
                scrollTop: y
            }, 100);
        }
    });

});
}(jQuery));
```

This code is not optimised so, it is only for didactic reasons.
The code looksup for the "ul" list every click, the y variable get's the relative coordinate by scrollTop() function of jQuery.
The step could also be constant 59 for instance or as I sad before calculated.

Then checks if y breaks a border on top or down, therefore it looks for the height downwards, and checks y against 0 upwards.
Rest is almost the same for up and down, only the sign changes from + to -.

Hope this helps. Code could be more reusable and optimized, todo the same with keypress.

Comment: hi, thanks for helping me out. quick question, why did you wrap the code with function($){}(jQuery)? does that have a optimization reason? or just because you are used to $?

Comment: ok. 
the step = the height of the first child + some margin.
scrollTop = all the pixels that are hidden in the ul?
but how come (h >= y) is good enough? I mean, y (the pixels hidden) are never the full height? it does seems to work, but I dont fully understand how.

Comment: @acriel I used function($) { ... } (jQuery) as a wrapper to use the $ in the inner anonymus function, 1. for convenience, 2. do not pollute global scope (local variable inside)

Comment: @acriel (h >= y) means the border at the bottom, you have to know how height the whole list (other ways are thinkable like measure the position of the bottom arrwow, and compare it with the current position). y is the current Position of the list, when you are at the bottom of the list, the position is same as the height of the list. You can look at your browser console to check the values to get a feelin for it.

Comment: thanks a lot for elaborating! it is a bit confusing, because the jQuery documentation says: "The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will be 0." [https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/]. But indeed, your (h >= y) works.

Comment: something else, if I click the arrows to fast, the animation is not executed, but the 'y += step;' is. do you know of a way to only execute the 'y += step;' if there's no animation going on?

Comment: @acriel: To avoid to fast clicking, you have to know if the animation is still running. A easy way is to put a helper variable like "running" set to false after the animation has stopped.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51686/discussion-between-acriel-and-robert)